# Retain Original Arguments Through Recursion (Javascript Preferred)

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm doing a regex parse for an alphanumeric sort to compare two arguments.  First I'm supposed to ignore the leading zeroes to make the token comparison.  But if all tokens are equal, the tokens with the leading zeroes are smaller.
So I do a regex like /(\D|[1-9])/ and parse through it recursively (compare the first tokens, if equal, pass back new strings minus the leading equal tokens via regex.exec(arg1, arg2).

But if everything is equal, I want do to the whole thing again with regex /(\D|0*\d)/ to capture leading zeroes.  I try to do this by returning a formula.  So original becomes:
function (arg1, arg2, orig1, orig2);

and then I return

function compare(arg1new, arg2new, arg1 ,arg2)

but what happens is that on a loop iteration, arg1new becomes arg1 which gets returned back in the orig1 spot...so I lose the original function argument and instead get the same argument just one loop behind.

Is there a way to hold the original arguments through all recursions...and invoke only at the end?

Example:

```
function alphanumericLess(s1, s2, orig1, orig2) {
    console.log(s1,s2);
    if(s1.length<1 && s2.length>=1){ //if 1st string is shorter
        return true;
    }
    var regex = /(\D|[1-9])(.*)/;
    var leadS1 = regex.exec(s1); //parse string1 ignoring leading zeroes
    var leadS2 = regex.exec(s2); //parse string2 ignoring leading zeroes

    if(leadS1[1]==leadS2[1]){ 
        console.log('if equals loop');
        return alphanumericLess(leadS1[2],leadS2[2],s1,s2);

    } else if(leadS1[1]<leadS2[1]){ 
        return true;
    }  else return false; //here is where I want to then re-run the recursion with /(\D|0*\d)/ to capture the leading zeroes comparison scenario
```

}

Comment: This is quite cryptic. Why not just show your code?

Comment: This may help with the parsing bit of tokens. If I understand your question right assume your token is `0001019191`. You need to use regex grouping to capture the parts `/(0*)([1-9a-zA-Z]\w*)/`. Using this regex with `exec` it will return `["0001019191", "000", "1019191"]`.

Comment: @trincot sorry first question, n00b mistake

Comment: It seems odd that you would want to only look at the preceding zeroes after comparing all tokens. So then `'1A' < '01B'` but `'1A' > '01A'`. That is quite counter intuitive. NB: your code has several issues.

Comment: @trincot from what I gather standard alphanumeric sorting frequently ignores leading zeroes until the end.  single, so '1A' vs. '01B' would be '1' vs '01' (equal for now), 'A' vs. 'B' (less).  In your latter case '1A' vs '01A', '1' vs '01' (equal for now), 'A' vs. 'A' (equal), go back and the token with the most leading zeroes is lesser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by creating a local functions inside your existing function, which will be called recursively instead of the existing one. Then you can call that local function in two different ways to launch the recursion twice.

There are also some issues with your current code:

- A comparison function should better be in line with the signature that is required for a `sort` callback, i.e. it should return a negative number when the first argument should be sorted before the second, 0 when they are equal, and 1 if the first should be sorted after the second.
- The regular expression only matches one character, but for a natural sort you should compare groups of digits with groups of digits, like in `12AB' and`123AB`, the comparison should be between 12 and 123, not with 'A' and 3.
- The ending condition at the start is not complete. You should also deal with the case when the second string is empty.
- The code will fail if you pass a string that ends with a zero. In that case the regular expression will not yield a result when only that zero is left over. It would be a lot easier if you would preprocess the strings to remove leading zeroes, including those that occur at the very end. Then in a second instance you could restart the recursion without such replacement, but in both cases using a regular expression that matches all characters (including 0).

Here is a solution:

```js
function alphanumericLess(s1, s2) {
    // Use a local function for the recursion, so it can be called twice
    function recurse(s1, s2) {
        if (!s1.length || !s2.length) { // test ALL end conditions
            // Don't return a boolean, but a numerical value
            return s1.length - s2.length; 
        }
        // Match multiple characters/digits as one part, deal with the 0 exclusion 
        // before calling the recurse function:
        var regex = /(\D+|\d+)(.*)/;
        var leadS1 = regex.exec(s1);
        var leadS2 = regex.exec(s2);
        if (leadS1[1] === leadS2[1]) { // Use strict comparison where possible
            return recurse(leadS1[2], leadS2[2]);
        } // After an if-return, else is not needed
        // As parts can have different lengths, use appropriate comparison method, 
        // and return a number that represents the comparison result
        if (isNaN(leadS1[1]) || isNaN(leadS2[1])) {
            return leadS1[1].localeCompare(leadS2[1]);
        }
        // In the numerical case, if equal, give precedence to the 
        // longest representation (zero-padded):
        return +leadS1[1] - +leadS2[1] || leadS2[1].length - leadS1[1].length;
    }
    // First call above function with leading zeroes removed.
    // If that yields equality, call it again without such removal:
    return recurse(s1.replace(/\b0+/g, ''), s2.replace(/\b0+/g, ''))
        || recurse(s1, s2);
}

console.log(alphanumericLess('012Ab3X0', '12Ab3X0')); // negative => order is correct
console.log(alphanumericLess('Ab30X0', 'Ab3X0')); // positive => order is reversed
console.log(alphanumericLess('Ab30X0', 'Ab30X0')); // zero => equal
// Use in sort: output is [ "001A", "1A", "2A", "B0999", "B0999X", "B999X" ]
console.log(['B999X', '1A', 'B0999', '001A', 'B0999X', '2A'].sort(alphanumericLess));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Remarks

The code for ignoring leading zeroes in the first sweep is left outside of the recursion: it is done with a one-shot removal of those leading zeroes. This way the recursive function is the same for both sweeps, just the arguments are different.

It is not efficient to execute a regular expression in each call of the recursive function. It would be more efficient to do a split of the strings before entering in the recursion. Of course, a non-recursive function would be even more efficient.

Finally, natural sort often also is case insensitive. You might want to put that logic in your function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode that shows an example:

```
function keep (a,b) {
  if (a == b) {
    return b;
  }
  else {
    return keep(a + 1, b);
  }
}
keep(1, 5);
```

B is passed all the way up and after that, all the way down again...